# Next Auth - Oauth

Tags: javascript, next.js, oauth, google-oauth, next-auth

I have my next app and It was working, but since today idk what whappend that im facing this error when i try to log in with google, Im using next auth and this is the request that I get:
[image]

[image]

and the terminals prints this:

[image]

How can I fix the problem? I've tried changing the client ID and Secret but still the same

this is the nextauth code:

```
const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    // OAuth authentication providers...
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
      authorizationUrl:
      "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?propmt=consent&access_type=offline&response_type=code",
    })
    
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ account, profile }) {
      if (account.provider === "google") {
        return profile.email_verified && profile.email.endsWith("@gmail.com")
      }
      return true // Do different verification for other providers that don't have `email_verified`
    },
    session: ({session, token, user}) => {
      if (adminEmails.includes(session?.user?.email)) {
        return session;
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
    },
  },
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)

export async function isAdminRequest(req,res) {
  const session = await getServerSession(req,res,authOptions);
  if (!adminEmails.includes(session?.user?.email)) {
    res.status(401);
    res.end();
    throw 'not admin';
  }
}
```

Comment: Voted to close this question as it was based on a typo (3000 vs 3001)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it, the error was simple just check the correct ports, i was using 3001 but i put on my settings 3000.

Answer (score 0):

```
     **You'll need to configure NextAuth.js to use your OAuth provider. This involves creating a file at pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js in your Next.js project with the following content, customized for your provider.**
    
    import NextAuth from "next-auth"
    import Providers from "next-auth/providers"
    export default NextAuth({
      providers: [
        Providers.ProviderName({
          clientId: process.env.PROVIDER_CLIENT_ID,
          clientSecret: process.env.PROVIDER_CLIENT_SECRET,
        }),
      ],`enter code here`
    })

**In your application, you can now use the NextAuth.js client to sign in users, check session status, and sign out. For example, to add a sign-in button:**

import { signIn, signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/client"

export default function Component() {
  const [session, loading] = useSession()
  return (
    <div>
      {!session && (
        <button onClick={() => signIn('providerName')}>Sign in</button>
      )}
      {session && (
        <div>
          <p>Signed in as {session.user.email}</p>
          <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign out</button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Running Your Application**